# Setting environment variable for Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, environment-variables

I have set the CLASSPATH and HOME_PATH for my JDK in the windows environment variables, do I need to set anything similar for Eclipse in order to compile Android programmes? 
The problem I'm having is that Eclipse can be opened and create a program as simple as the Helloworld example, seems to be not an exact way to compile and then I can pack into any execution file so my little Android phone can install with.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried installing the standard Eclipse Android add-on? That worked easily enough for me, though I develop on a Mac so details may be different try this quickly googled link - http://apcmag.com/installing-the-eclipse-android-plugin.htm

Answer (score 0):

Android requires more than just Java, but also the Android SDK. To get it working with Eclipse, you'll also need the Eclipse Android plugin.  So, if you can run the HelloWorld program, Java is working.  Follow instructions to get Android working here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Also, there's a couple links under the "ADT Bundle" section to just download a self-contained version of Eclipse bundled with the Android SDK to save you from installing the Eclipse Android plugin and configuring anything.  You'll unzip the folder in a convenient directory, then see two folders: the Android SDK and another containing Eclipse.  You can just run the Eclipse.exe in the Eclipse folder and your Android environment is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the android SDK? If not, get it  [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It comes with eclipse IDE with all the required things already set up.